# Show that if two integers are in this relation then so are their powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$a\sim b$ is defined as $m$ divides $b-a$, where $m$ is some fixed arbitrary positive integer.

> Assume $A\sim a$. Show $A^n\sim a^n$ for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: You can read about [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Also, if you first verify the rule that $A\sim a, B\sim b$ together imply $AB\sim ab$, you can prove this by induction on $n$.

Comment: Reworded, you ask: If $m\mid a-A$ then prove that $m\mid a^n-A^n$.  Note that $a^n-A^n = (a-A)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}A+a^{n-3}A^2+\dots+aA^{n-2}+A^{n-1})$

Comment: I tried to edit the title to be more searchable. I am sure that this is a duplicate, so that is important. You are welcome to improve it further.

Comment: It's sufficient to show (A-a)|A^n-a^n.  Have you ever seen any statement about A-a and A^n-a^n that would indicate this might be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: since $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$

$$A^n-a^n=(A-a)(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}a+\ldots+Aa^{n-2}+a^{_n-1})$$

Comment: Did you search for a duplicate first, or do you think this is the first time this question has been asked here?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If you're asking me: I don't even try to look for duplicates in most cases of such elementary questions. As the "search" thing here is so not user-friendly it is almost impossible to do a decent search in many cases, perhaps in most of the cases. For one, the search engine does not accept MathJax and that's already a problem. Thus, when a question is so simple and I can address it I do it almost at once: much quicker than doing the search. Yet if I know it is a duplicate and I know I can locate it easily and I am in the mood then yes: I tell the OP to go to a duplicate.